# Is there a Windows equivalent to PyVirtualDisplay

Tags: python, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

I have written a web scraper for a mate to save him time at work.  It is written in `Python`, using `Selenium` and opening a Firefox browser.

I have written this code myself on a Linux machine I use `PyVirtualDisplay` so Firefox doesn't actually open and disturb my work.

How can I make it run within a virtual display on a Windows PC?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for virtual display on a Windows PC? (not using `--headless`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you can not run `PyVirtualDisplay` on Windows is that PyVirtualDisplay uses Xvfb as it's display and Xvfb is a headless display server for the X Window System, Windows does not use the X Window System.

**not recommended**

So... what you can do if you insist on working with PyVirtualDisplay is to change the `Display(visible=True)` Or you can set the backend as is shown in the API [here](https://pyvirtualdisplay.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#pyvirtualdisplay.Display).

**My recommendation**

Don't use `PyVirtualDisplay` you can use any webdriver such as Chrome driver and just add ChromeOptions with `--headless`.

Or in your case you use firefox so it would look something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
driver.quit()
```

For more updated info just have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode#Selenium_in_Python).

Hope this helps you!