# Firefox runs in background in Selenide

Tags: selenium, gecko, selenide

usually, questions are in opposite way, how to make a Firefox run to be in the background. I have written some time ago some basic tests in Selenide, but when today I tried to run it (as usual) on a server, I got an error

```
SessionNotCreatedException
```

I started to look for the result and I noticed, that when I'm running now tests locally from my computer, Firefox does not appear. I can see Firefox's tasks in Task manager, I got an error with a done screenshot, but the browser does not open.

I noticed there is plenty of questions about how to run tests with the headless option, but I need something opposite, this might be a problem with `SessionNotCreatedException`, the server does not see the browser.

As I know Selenide runs the newest gecko driver (it's updating). I tried to set some options in the beginning:

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setCapability("marionette", false);
    options.setCapability("headless", false);
```

and also updated Selenide to 5.0.0, but it's still failing

EDIT: I can't use any other browsers

Comment: Did you consider trying Xvfb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running tests on a server generally, the server is an X window system so the way to do it is to run a virtual display.

Using [Xvfb](https://pypi.org/project/xvfbwrapper/) is the best way for that! you can read about it [here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless).

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

with Xvfb() as xvfb:
    # launch virtual display here.
    # start your webdrivr in the virtual display
```

Or you can use `PyVirtualDisplay` [link here](https://pypi.org/project/PyVirtualDisplay/).

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

**Note**

Make sure your server is an X Window System!

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700598/8179099) it doesn't work on windows.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank's, I'll check it :)